# Exclude latest version of dependent projects in Scala

Tags: scala, sbt

I changed **scalaVertion 2.10.5 to 2.11.7 and sbtVersion** also. And
I am compiling one of the projects **mycompany-sales** projects, It has dependency with **mycompany-common** project.

My jars will create like this. **mycompany--ScalaVersion-localversion-SNAPSHOT**.

But here, I am not changing anything in **mycompany-common**. So, i want to use old one of mycompany-common jars, what I am using earlier.

After I compile after scala version change I am getting error like this:

> [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
> [warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
>
> [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
> [warn]  :: com.mycompany#mycompany-common-read_2.11;2.9.57: not found
>
> [warn]  :: com.mycompany#mycompany-common-write_2.11;2.9.57: not found
>
> [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

I am using mycompany-common-read_2.10-2.9.57, I need to use same after Scala version change in mycompany-sales also.

What do I have to do in build.sbt?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You need to compile your company libs with Scala 2.11. Then this will get resolved automatically.

Comment: is there any alternative?

Comment: As far as i know, there is no other way. You have to cross compile against 2.11

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use groupID `%` artifactID % revision, not groupID `%%` artifactID % revision

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be able to compile `mycompany-common-read` with Scala 2.11 without making any changes there:

```
> sbt // in mycompany-common-read directory
> ++2.11.7
> publishLocal
```

Whether this works, depends on its own implementation (and of course, if it has dependencies with the same problem).

Comment: Then you are out of luck, unfortunately. You can try using atline's approach, but it isn't even remotely guaranteed to work.